# Is it possible to run Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 in a CentOS 6.0 x64 environment

Tags: sql-server-2008, centos6

Is it possible to install SQL Server DataCenter 2008 R2 on Centos 6? My goal is to use an OpenVZ machine as my data tier in my SharePoint farm configuration. If so does anyone know the series of command lines I would need to run? I already have the SQL program exe file loaded to a temp directory on the server?

I already imaged the openVZ vPS, created a folder and uploaded the SQL Server exe files.

If possible do you have any tips?

Comment: No. Windows is the only operating system SQL Server can run on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to install SQL Server DataCenter 2008 R2 on Centos 6?

No, it will not run on CentOS 6 as CentOS is not a supported operating system; you can only run it on supported versions of Windows.